# Bash if-condition inside Makefile on macOs BigSur gives syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, makefile

I have this code inside Makefile

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

define PYTHON_VERSION
3.7.4
endef

define DEFAULT
echo BUILD_ENV:

  if [ -z "$(PYTHON_VERSION)" ]
  then
    printf '$(PYTHON_VERSION) is empty.\n'
    exit 1
  fi
endef

default:
    $(DEFAULT)

build:
    $(DEFAULT)
```

It gives me (running `make build`):

> echo BUILD_ENV:
> BUILD_ENV:
> if [ -z "3.7.4" ] then printf '3.7.4 is empty.\n' exit 1
> /bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

How to fix this error? (it happens on macOs BigSur)

Comment: Is your code supposed to be a bash script, or a Makefile?

Comment: @ShaneBishop this code is inside Makefile and I run it with `make build`

Comment: Why do you have a colon at the end of `echo BUILD_ENV:`?

Comment: @ShaneBishop I am trying to use legacy code, but deleting the : doesn't help anyway

Comment: Same problem as the issue marked as dup

Comment: (note, just sticking something inside a variable doesn't free you from the responsibility of making it into one logical line)

Comment: @MadScientist I checked and code works on my ubuntu but not on macos

Comment: @MadScientist I resolved the issue. It was because my gnu version was outdated. Could you vote to reopen? I want to add answer and resolve the question. It is not duplicate as here the issue is in the GNU make version

Comment: There is no version of GNU make where your makefile shown above will work.  You _must_ modify your `define`d value to contain appropriate semicolons and backslashes so that they become a single logical line, as described in the duplicate.  That's true for all versions of GNU make.